Error in joint modeling of the JM package in R
I am running a joint modeling of a linear mixed model and a Cox model as below.
rbcLME <- lme(log(RBC.counts+1)~time+time:DAC, random = ~1|ID, 
          data=no.missing.rbc)
rbcSURV <- coxph(Surv(surv.time, death) ~ GroupforDCAtreatment, 
             data = rbc.df, x = TRUE)
rbc.JM <- jointModel(rbcLME, rbcSURV, timeVar = "time", 
                 method = "piecewise-PH-GH")


 Error in optim(thetas, opt.survPC, gr.survPC, method = "BFGS", control = list(maxit = if (it <  : 
      non-finite value supplied by optim

I found same question in Stack Overflow, but seems not answers were given.
It would be great if someone can provide R code to fix the error. your text

can you share your data?

Yes, I can, but do not know how to upload the data? Send to you directly? William

you can edit your question to include it, in your r session run the code dput(yourdf) where yourdf is your data.frame and copy the contents of that into the question. you will have to do it for both the longitudinal data and survival data. if the data are very large only include a subset of the data

one thing I noticed is that you are not including the main effect for DAC in the longitudinal model, you are only including the interaction. are DAC and GroupforDCAtreatment the same variable?
